# How do you create a table in html

Tags: html

I am currently making a forum in html,but I can't seem to find a site to tell me how to insert a table

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.

Comment: If you can't put a table in html, perhaps you shouldn't be starting by writing a forum, I think you should do a lot of tutorials and at least have a basic knowledge before moving onto more advanced things like forums

Comment: @Ghost267, what code have you tried so far? If you improve the quality of the question, others will be better able to help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```html
<table border="1">
  <tr>
    <td>Some text</td>
    <td>Some text</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Some text</td>
    <td>Some text</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

`<tr>` stands for a row

`<td>` is a cell in the row

Answer (score 0):

http://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/content/tables/

Check this out if you'd like to start using tables with bootstrap.
This will open up the ability to have responsiveness and a few options when creating tables.

Answer (score -1):

```
<thead><th>HEADER1 </th><th>HEADER2 </th></thead>
<tr>
<td> Insert content </td>
<td> Insert content </td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, including an explanation of *how* and *why* this solves the problem [would really help](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now!  Please [edit] your answer to add explanation, and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.